# Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, load, filtering

I was trying to do this referring to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg715120%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

I tried this :

```
dbContext.Entry(entry) _
    .Collection(Function(c) c.relObjects) _
    .Query() _
    .Where(Function(c) c.MyCondition) _
    .Load()
```

But it does not compile, saying that Load() is not a member of IQueryable

I saw that it targets EF5.
Is there a way to have it work in EF4 ?

Comment: C# or VB.NET? You tagged the question by `c#` by use `vb.net` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but make sure that you import the `System.Data.Entity` namespace:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
```

The `.Load` method is actually an extension method in that namespace.

Comment: You star, that's what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

The Where condition return an IQueryable object.
You should use the **Load** after the collection of releated objects:

```
dbContext.Entry(entry).Collection(Function(c) c.relObjects).Load()
```

[From msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg715120%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) : *Even with lazy loading disabled it is still possible to lazily load related entities by using an explicit call to the Load method on the related entity’s entry. For example*:

```
// Load the department related to a given course using a string      
context.Entry(course).Reference("Department").Load();      
// Load the courses related to a given department 
context.Entry(department).Collection(Function(c) c.Courses).Load();
```